# Dropdowns to hide when clicking outside, with a CKeditor instance to complex things

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, dropdown

I have many tables, in different tabs, with an "`Actions`" link for each row. Clicking on "`Actions`" opens a dropdown, and this works like a dropdown should: clicking outside closes dropdown, clicking inside keeps dropdown open. So far so good, a simplified version is here https://jsfiddle.net/ivanhalen/nya69pd2/30/

The relevant JS part is this:

```
$('.show_actions').on('click', function(){
    var el = $(this);
  el.closest('tbody').find('.actions').hide();
  el.closest('td').find('.actions').show();
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
  var el = $(document).find('.actions').off('click');
  if (!el.is(e.target) && el.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    el.hide();
  }
});
```

Now another actor comes into the scene

In other tabs I have some content-editable divs. Clicking on them call a CKEditor instance and opens a custom dropdown (I call "palette") with CKE stuff: buttons, fields, etc.

Well, here the same should happen: when clicking outside the "palette" it should close (and destroy CKEditor instance), clicking inside should keep open

The code I wrote does not work well, and I struggle to find  a working solution: here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ivanhalen/nya69pd2/32/

The relevant code is:

```
$('.show_actions').on('click', function(){
    var el = $(this);
  el.closest('tbody').find('.actions').hide();
  el.closest('td').find('.actions').show();
  $(document).find('.palette').hide();
});

$('.editor').on('click', function(){
    var el = $(this);  
  $(document).find('.actions').hide();
  el.closest('.editor_container').find('.palette').show();
  // here call a function to instantiate CKeditor
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
  var el = $(document).find('.actions, .palette').off('click');
  if (!el.is(e.target) && el.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    el.hide();    
    if (el.hasClass('palette')){
        console.log('here destroy CKeditor instance too');      
    }
  }
});
```

The `'here destroy CKeditor instance too'` is always triggered, even clicking on content-editable-div where I should create intead

Please, any help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if there's some subtle *trap* in your logic.

As you assign `el` like this:

```
var el = $(document).find('.actions, .palette').off('click');
```

then this `if()` check will be always *true*:

```
if (el.hasClass('palette')){
    console.log('here destroy CKeditor instance too');      
}
```

Also, can't figure out if your nested `if()`s inside the `mouseup` event will do the job correctly.

I tried to change a bit the *mouseup* event code and it seems to me - if I understood well your goal - that it does the work:

```
$(document).on("mouseup", function (e) {
  var el = $(document).find(".actions, .palette").off("click");
  
  // first if() check to close the dropdowns
  if (!el.is(e.target) && el.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    el.hide();
  }

  // separate if() check, to decide if destroy the instance
  // check if my target is NOT the editor
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass("editor")) {
    console.log("here destroy CKeditor instance too");
  }
});
```